# What is the right way to add Java code to a Cordova Android app?

Tags: java, android, cordova, plugins

I am working on an Cordova Android app.  As part of the app, I wrote some Java classes to create a service using WorkManager to poll our server and send a notification to the client on certain events.

Right now the code is invoked through MainActivity.java, where I create the worker, and all of the classes sit in the Java folder under the Android Platform directory.  My understanding is that this isn't ideal since my code will get dropped every time we want to reset the platform.

What is the right way to add this code to a project and is there a tutorial that I can follow?  Should it all be a plugin?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely refactor your code into a plugin. Check out the doc [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/)
You can make your plugin for Android only as well.

I would recommend too, to clone a very simple plugin and check out the code.